# How to use Flickr Oauth authentication for Private photosets?

Tags: php, jquery, json, oauth, flickr

I am curious if it is possible to authenticate a web app, only once, to access your private photosets through Flickr?

Currently any of the tutorials or ideas I have had/seen use the generic randomly generated tokens that Oauth provides.  Thus meaning, I have to have the user of the web app click to authorize each and every time they want to view a specific photoset.

How do I make it so that I can use my web app to access my own Private photosets and validate only once, so that other users dont have to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a user authorizes you access to their account, flickr will send back to you an OAuth token. OAuth tokens are long lived, you can use them repeatedly until the user revokes/removes the authorization. Save them in your database and associate it the user. Note: OAuth token tokens are unique to application (domain/realm) + user.

This is where a user would [typically revoke a permission](http://www.flickr.com/services/auth/list.gne?from=extend).

Comment: Yes, I discovered this.  I was afraid that the tokens offered expired but that is not the case.  Therefor it does work by authenticating (once) and storing in the database.